# On these pictures of accelerator equipment, what are the blue metal things?

Tags: accelerator-physics

I have visited many accelerator, and these **blue things**

[image: blue]

can be seen where cryo technology is used. What are they (He valves?/safety valves?) Why is so many needed?

**Edit:**

Here there are more blue things seen mounted on top of the helium line behind the LHC.

[image: More blue things]

Comment: My guess, and only a guess, they are arrays of klystrons. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klystron . "to produce high-power carrier waves for communications and the driving force for modern particle accelerators."  see also http://www.terragalleria.com/california/picture.usca30493.html

Comment: No not klystrons - there is no HV, or waveguides. It has something to do with cryo cooling.

Comment: If you read up, there are klystrons used for superconducting magnets."The superconducting section of the linac employs eighty one 6-cell cavities power by eighty one 550 kW, 805 MHz klystrons." http://accelconf.web.cern.ch/accelconf/a04/PAPERS/MOM403.PDF. They are a sort of power supply.

Comment: @anna v: Why would I need to read up-when I know what a klystron is!? -They are not a sort of power supply -read your own wiki link. The klystrons that drives the LCH are several meters high.

Comment: @annav, the cavities that are powered by klystrons is implying the accelerating force in the cavities is generated by the klystrons. The magnets themselves will not be powered by high power RF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd guess they are valve actuators. A quick Google found an example at http://www.ge-energy.com/products_and_services/products/valves_control_and_safety/masoneilan_type_87_88_pneumatic_multi_spring_actuators.jsp